# Realm forces to add @objc word while defining dynamic variables

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I am currently playing around with RealmSwift and in the tutorial of Marin Todorov, he created variables like this and compiler doesn't complain.[image: realm tutorial image]

But whenever I try to create those variables by myself, compiler wants me to add `@objc` word[image: compiler error]

Are those different things or do they behave differently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That tutorial is written in September 2016, which is quite outdated.

It used to be that if you have a class that is exposed to Objective-C, then all its members are exposed to Objective-C. In Swift 4, things that are not marked with `@objc` are not exposed to Objective-C, regardless of whether it is a member of a `@objc` class.

Realm needs to do dynamic stuff on your properties, like KVO. That's why `dynamic` is needed. But `dynamic` is a feature exclusive to stuff that is exposed to Objective-C, which is why you need `@objc`.

This is also why Realm can't handle Swift optionals, because they can't be bridged to Objective-C. You have to use `RealmOptional<T>`.

In short, just add `@objc` to your properties and everything will be fine.

Answer (score 3):

They are different:

- `@objc` means expose the object to the Objective-C runtime
- `dynamic` means enable key-value observing (KVO) for the object.

KVO requires the Objective-C runtime.

The behavior of [@objc inference has changed in Swift 4 (SE-0160)](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0160-objc-inference.md)

Comment: thanks a lot. the first one was compiled in swift 3.3 so that is the reason